# How to close previous opened sub menu when clicked on next submenu on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have one menu with sub menu.I have to open a drop down menu when clicked and closes again on when  clicked on other menu. My below code both the drop down displaying if I clicked on menu. I have to display only one drop down at a time. Would you help me in this?

**Note** In second `li` tag I am using `div` tag

```js
$('.sub-menu').hide();
   $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
     $("ul",this).slideDown();
  });
```

```css
.menu ul.nav-menu{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
<ul class="nav-menu">
 
<li class="main-list"><a href="#">home</a>

 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="#">home1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li class="main-list"><a href="#">service</a>
  <div class="square">
  <div class="sub">
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li><a href="#">home1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` like below:-

```js
$('.sub-menu').hide();
$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
  $(".main-list").find('.sub-menu').slideUp();
  $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown();
});
```

```css
.menu ul.nav-menu{
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
   <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="main-list"><a href="#">home</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">home1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-list"><a href="#">service</a>
          <div class="square">
            <div class="sub">
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">home1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Anant, Working perfectly for me. Upvote from my side

Comment: @NarendraVerma  thhanks for up-vote. Please mark it  also to make it you accepted answer. As you said it's working perfect for you.

Comment: Sure, I will accept after 7 min. one more help i need can you help me with script like I have to click on menu icon the display all my menu and icon will change to close icon

Comment: @NarendraVerma  please ask it as a new question, and for-sure you will get help for that too.Thanks

Comment: @AlivetoDie Hi m stucked on the same problem but the framework is angular5 and I am using Angular2-Material Mat-Menu. how to achieve same thing in it.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the last opened sub menu in a variable and close it when you open another menu:

```
var lastOpen = null;
$('.sub-menu').hide();
$("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
    if (lastOpen != null){
         lastOpen.hide();
         lastOpen = null;
    }
    lastOpen = $("ul",this).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: This solution works well for my purposes. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

According to which element was clicked, it shows up the corresponding submenu.

```js
$('.sub-menu').hide();
$(".main-list").click(function() {
  $(".main-list").find('.sub-menu').hide();
  $(this).find('.sub-menu').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.menu ul.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <ul class="nav-menu">

    <li class="main-list"><a href="#">home</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">home1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="main-list"><a href="#">service</a>
      <div class="square">
        <div class="sub">
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">home1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">home2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Kind user, Working for me.Upvote from my side

Comment: Mr.Kind user, Reason is only SlideUp and slideDown, Your script is directly hide and accepted answer is smoothly hiding .